# An 'abstract' at the start of every chapter?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, abstract

I am using the book document class and what I would like to do is to have a abstract like text at the start of every chapter (in smaller font outlining what will happen in the chapter, etc.). I don't have a problem changing to amsbook if that helps in anyway.

Example: [http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Introduction-Modern-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038797329X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797329X)

Comment: The memoir document class has a built in `chapterprecis` which looks like it does what you want...

Comment: I see but then I have never worked with the memoir class, it seems so overly complicated ...

Comment: Is it easier to start with Latex and add some extra classes or directly learn memoir or Koma?

Comment: My answer is this 2 minute video link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF2lCIFoRlI

Comment: @Hesam Part of the benefit of LaTeX is that changing the class doesn't necessarily require significant changes (if any) to the body of the document. Changing `book` to `memoir` on its own shouldn't change anything about your document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example that uses one of the KOMA-Script classes to achieve a similar effect:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=auto, version=last, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\S\enspace\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictum}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\large}
\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\noindent}


\begin{document}


\setchapterpreamble{%
  \dictum{%
    The notion of prime number is fundamental in number theory.
    The first part of this chapter is devoted to proving that every integer can be written as a product of primes in an essentially unique way.

    After that, we shall prove an analogous theorem in the ring of polynomials over a field.%
  }%
  \vspace{24pt}%
}

\chapter{Unique Factorization}

\section{Unique Factorization in $\mathbb Z$}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice example of KOMA-Script.

Comment: Is it easier to learn Latex and add some extra classes or directly learn memoir or Koma?

Answer (score 13):

I just use

```
\begin{quote}
{\small ...}
\end{quote}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can define a similar abstract environment to your example using

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{\rightskip1in\itshape}{}
```

Just use `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` after your `\chapter` and then start a `\section` after that.

Comment: I get an error "Abstract already defined". Could you advise on what to do please?

Comment: @user130222 then just call it something else like `ChapterAbstract`

Answer (score 4):

[image: Output]

Abstract at the beginning of the chapter can be inserted using "**quote environment**". To avoid repetition of the commands at the beginning of each chapter, a "\newcommand" environment is created as preamble. Here I have created a newcommand called "\chapterabstract". For the lines above and below the abstract '\rule' command has been used and to avoid the **white space** after the bottom line of the abstract '\vskip' command has been used. \lipsum environment is used for the dummy text.

```
%===============Chapter abs by Chas============
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{times,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\newcommand{\chapabstract}[1]{
    \begin{quote}
        \singlespacing\small
        \rule{14cm}{1pt}
        #1
        \vskip-4mm
        \rule{14cm}{1pt}
\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{An Abstract at the Start of Each Chapter}
\chapabstract{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[2-3]
 
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapabstract{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF2lCIFoRlI

Comment: Is there a way to make rules as large as the quote ? If one want use a different geometry parameters