# multiple abstracts and keywords apa7 package

Tags: abstract, keywords, apa7

I am writing my dissertation using the apa7 package by Daniel Weiss (https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7?lang=en). However, since it is a dissertation I need to include an abstract and keywords for each of my included studies. If I use the `\abstract` command multiple times, all abstracts after the first one disappear. When I use `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` the text just shows up normally, not on a separate page, no 'abstract' heading, and no keywords.

Is there a way I can tweak the preamble or the class to allow multiple abstracts and keywords? I looked at this question [Two abstracts needed in apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119292/two-abstracts-needed-in-apa6/119335#119335) which is similar, but all of my abstracts / keywords are in english.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. What is an 'included study'? Does your dissertation contain chapters based on (your own) published papers, and you want an abstract for each chapter? Or do you want to list abstracts and keywords in the bibliography at the end of the dissertation? Or do you want abstracts and keywords in the main text, with the text of the abstract found in the `.bib` file?

Comment: @Marijn the first one! I have a chapter for each of my papers, and each chapter should contain an abstract and keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, `apa7` is based on the `article` class and therefore it does not have chapters (`\section` is the 'highest' level). The `apa7` class also seems primarily intended for individual articles, and not for dissertations. Is there any reason you use this class? And how do you use it exactly? Could you create an example document, with only two chapters, and no contents for the chapters apart from the title?

Comment: I am not bound to the apa7 class, my dissertation is in psychology, so I thought it would be a good starting point. However, I am already running into multiple issues (e.g., the lack of chapters as well, as you said) so I might look into alternatives.

Comment: In that case maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/an-abstract-at-the-start-of-every-chapter/ can help you.